# Is it possible to give one asyncio task a higher priority to achieve a more precise timout handling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Given a list of tasks that are io and cpu bound. When waiting for them using `asyncio.wait` with a timeout, the timout is triggered very late. Is it possible to prioritize the pending timeout?

This example defines workers that simulate 1 second cpu and 1 second io bound operations. It runs some of them in parallel and waits for 10 seconds.

```
async def worker():
    for _ in range(200):
        # approx one second of cpu bound operations
        for _ in range(10000000):
            random.random()

        # one second of io bound operations
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main(num_tasks):
    tasks = []
    for _ in range(num_tasks):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(worker()))

    time_start = time.monotonic()
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=10)
    print(f'with {num_tasks} tasks waited for {time.monotonic() - time_start:.3}s')

    for task in pending:
        task.cancel()

for num_tasks in range(1, 11):
    asyncio.run(main(num_tasks))
```

With an increasing number of tasks, the timeout is getting less and less accurate.

```
with 1 tasks waited for 10.0s
with 2 tasks waited for 10.9s
with 3 tasks waited for 11.5s
with 4 tasks waited for 12.0s
with 5 tasks waited for 13.2s
with 6 tasks waited for 14.2s
with 7 tasks waited for 15.6s
with 8 tasks waited for 16.8s
with 9 tasks waited for 17.9s
with 10 tasks waited for 18.6s
```

It seems to me that the main coroutine, whose timeout should be triggered, is not scheduled immediately when one of the workers suspends itself by `asyncio.sleep`. Multiple workers are scheduled before the pending timeout is processed. The underlying callback scheduled with `loop.call_later` seems to be treated like any other task.

Is it possible to tell the event loop to prioritize the main task or any pending callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event loop doesn't support the kind of priorities that you are after. Asyncio expects all operations carried out inside the event loop coroutines and callbacks to be "quick" - exactly how quick is a matter of interpretation, but they need to be fast enough not to affect the latency of the program.

To support CPU-bound execution, there is `run_in_executor`, which submits the given operation to a thread pool and suspends the current coroutine until it is done, allowing other coroutines to make progress. In your case the worker would look like this:

```
def cpu_bound():
    for _ in range(10000000):
        random.random()

async def worker():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for _ in range(200):
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, cpu_bound)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Modified like that, your program waits for ~10s regardless of the number of tasks.

In Python 3.9 and later, you can also use [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately we can not change the worker since it is in a library.
On a low level I found that there is loop.call_soon which schedules an event for the next iteration. asyncio.wait unfortunately uses loop.call_later.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L510
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon